# Unable to use RANK, OVER, WINDOW functions in MySQL Workbench v8.0.1

Tags: mysql, window-functions, rank, dense-rank

I'm using MySQL Workbench v8.0.1 as per the below version check and still unable to use functions like `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()`, `WINDOW`, `OVER`, `PRECEDING`, `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, and all others which should be supported in v8.0 and above.

**My query:**

```
WITH daily_shipping_summary AS 
( 
    SELECT ship_date, SUM(shipping_cost) AS daily_total FROM market_fact_full AS m
    INNER JOIN shipping_dimen AS s
    ON s.ship_id = m.ship_id
    GROUP BY ship_date
)
SELECT *,
SUM(daily_total) OVER w1 AS running_total,
AVG(daily_total) OVER w2 AS moving_avg
FROM daily_shipping_summary
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY daily_total ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
w2 AS (ORDER BY daily_total ROWS 6 PRECEDING)
```

***Getting this below error:***
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'w1 AS running_total, AVG(daily_total) OVER w2 AS moving_avg FROM daily_shipp' at line 10`

Could anyone please help me in how to get this resolved?

**MySQL Workbench version details**:

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| innodb_version | 8.0.1 |
| protocol_version | 10 |
| tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1 |
| version | 8.0.1-dmr-log |
| version_comment | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |

Comment: thanks! updated the screenshot... but still `PRECEDING` or `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` are also not working.

Comment: If you're not going to reuse a window spec it's usually clearer to just declare it inline eg `SUM(w) OVER(PARTITION BY x, y ORDER BY z ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` or whatever simplification/abbreviation you want to make

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: The workbench version is not relevant; workbench is just a client. what does `select version();` show?

Comment: There's another typo too. Multiple WINDOW are like multiple WITH; `WINDOW w1 as (...), w2 as (...)`, you don't repeat the word WINDOW

Comment: I think the version is 8.0.1. That result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'` did show the MySQL version (and more) as can be seen [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ed84687c3c7a439e2a7ec8101a62fb3)

Comment: *Getting this below error:* Always provide **complete and unchanged** error message text, not a part of it. If the client cuts off a part of the message then obtain its complete text via CLI.

Comment: If you are truly running 8.0.1 of the server, that is very unusual and unfortunate; versions 8.0.0 through 8.0.4 were development or release candidates, not for production use

Comment: Updated the Error Code with the complete content.

Comment: Many version 8 features were incomplete or buggy in the early development versions before the first GA version 8.0.11.  you should stop trying to work with 8.0.1 and install a new version.  You may need to export and reimport your data; I believe upgrading from development versions is technically unsupported.  If you feel you have to keep your version, you should avoid trying to use any features not in 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Use the word WINDOW once, then do `name as (spec), name2 as (spec2)` after it

[Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9JgmEqjb67aseByJhkdshd/2)

See comment about doing it inline if you don't plan to reuse the window spec (or prefer do it inline most the time even if the spec is reused, which is what we tend to do because it avoids having to jump around the sql to work out what does what)

Comment: yes, that was a typo... now updated my query but still these unable to use these functions

Comment: See that example i posted; it has a create table and a demonstrably working query on the right that uses two different window functions (the results are relatively nonsense but that doesn't matter..) - if you take that query pair exactly and paste it into your setup, does it work or not? (In which case I'd say you may have to bite the bullet ysth is offering and upgrade your MySQL - I'd test it for you if I could find a version of 8.0.1)

Comment: still not working... I think the reply from `ysth` is the reason!
`"Many version 8 features were incomplete or buggy in the early development versions before the first GA version 8.0.11."`